# Why isn't this simple sign up page working?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I'm not sure why this isn't working, It is giving me no errors, but it won't display the results. I just want to display the results of the 3 text fields. The next step I want to go about doing is entering the data into a database, then displaying it, but I guess that will come next. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
$Pword = $_POST["Pword"];

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if page is not

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

First name<input name="Fname" type="text" maxlength="12"
/>
<br />
<br />

Last name<input name="Lname" type="text" maxlength="12"
/>
<br />
<br />

<!--Address <input name="register_address" type="text" maxlength="12"
/>
<br />
 <br />-->
<!--<select name="state" value="State"></select>-->


Password<input name="Pword" type="text" maxlength="12"
/>
<br />
<br />

<!--Re-type Password<input name="register_password_confirm" type="text" maxlength="12"
/>
<br />
<br />-->

<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />



</form>

<?
} else {
echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname.".<br />";
echo "Your Password is, " .$Pword.".<br />";
}
?>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the form displays but nothing shows up when you submit it? Have you tried using var_dump or print_r to view the form data coming through?

Answer (score 3):

Three issues I see

**1 - Your button is not a submit button**

Change:

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

to

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**2 - Register globals may be turned off**

Change:

```
<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
```

**3 - Short open tags may be turned off**

Change:

```
<?
} else {
echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname.".<br />";
echo "Your Password is, " .$Pword.".<br />";
}
?>
```

to

```
<?php
} else {
echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname.".<br />";
echo "Your Password is, " .$Pword.".<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button needs to be changed to `type="submit"`, also you might want to move your variable declarations within the else statement to avoid PHP warnings:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and:

```
<?php
} else {
    $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
    $Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
    $Pword = $_POST["Pword"];
    echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname.".<br />";
    echo "Your Password is, " .$Pword.".<br />";
}
?>
```

Lastly, I would reduce the amount of html you put it the `if` statement to the bare minimum, this could cause conflicts if you change how the condition is handled in the future:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if page is not
        ?>
        <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            First name<input name="Fname" type="text" maxlength="12" /><br /><br />
            Last name<input name="Lname" type="text" maxlength="12" /><br /><br />
            <!--Address <input name="register_address" type="text" maxlength="12" /> <br /> <br />-->
            <!--<select name="state" value="State"></select>-->
            Password<input name="Pword" type="text" maxlength="12" /><br /><br />
            <!--Re-type Password<input name="register_password_confirm" type="text" maxlength="12" /><br /><br />-->
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
    } else {
        $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
        $Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
        $Pword = $_POST["Pword"];
        echo "Hello, ".$Fname." ".$Lname.".<br />";
        echo "Your Password is, " .$Pword.".<br />";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
```

and checking for

```
$_POST['submitted'] == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try echoing the result like this:

```
echo "Hello, $Fname $Lname.<br />
      Your Password is, $Pword.<br />";
```

I forgot to add that you don't need the dots after variables when echoing using double quotations.